# How to add a few non-related pages without affecting SEO?

Tags: seo, google, forum

I have a technology related forum. All posts are technology related articles. Currently there was a user request for adding a few online games to the site, and there was a huge amount of upvotes for that post. That means users would like for that...

So I thought to add a few open source online games for this. All those pages will be non-related to the current content.

How can I add those non-related pages without negatively affecting my entire site's SEO?

Comment: Many forums have off topic sections. Increased traffic/fresher content will improve your overall SEO. If you have tons of traffic for the new section (millions of page views per month) then put the game forum on a separate domain. Otherwise diluting your audience is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could noindex the pages therefore keeping search away from them.